# Unable to update python interpreter in rstudio

Tags: python, r, rstudio

I know this question has been asked a number of times but none of the extant solutions have worked for me. I need a way to update the python interpreter in rstudio. I can only use 3.11.5 or lower. Anything I set at 3.12 will not work (see error below). I tried adding the correct path to the .Renviron, .Rprofile, I tried replacing the path of 3.11.5 with the new version, I tried altering the files in the .virtualenvs to the updated version, I tried uninstalling Rstudio and reinstalling, etc., nothing works. I am able to use the correct python version in pycharm, visual studio, etc. It is only Rstudio that I am unable to use anything above 3.11.5.

```
Error in python_config_impl(python) : 
  Error 1 occurred running /usr/local/bin/python3.12: 
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
  running command ''/usr/local/bin/python3.12' '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/reticulate/config/config.py' 2>/dev/null' had status 1
```

Despite the actual global settings, 3.11.5 is launched and not 3.12. Complete mystery what is going on here.

[image]

Comment: you can try with an older reticulate version (1.24/1.22 or earlier) - i don't remember exactly which, but newer reticulate distributions do sometimes have trouble working with some python distributions. apart from that reticulate prefers the python dist with the most recent numpy version. what happens when you [set the python path in the r session](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html)?